# reinstall barnes and noble software on a rooted nook color?

Tags: installation

Is there a way to re-install Barnes and Noble software on a Nook Color that has been wiped and installed with gingerbread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&drKey=1359&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D914690&v=1&libid=1308747625025&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.etoile-laconnex.com%2Fnook-complete-restore-1.0.1.zip&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fandroid.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F10751%2Freinstall-barnes-and-noble-software-on-a-rooted-nook-color&title=%5BRECOVERY%5D%5BZIP%5D%20Nook%20Color%20Restore%20to%20stock%20-%20xda-developers&txt=here) is the firmware for your device's original software (v. 1.0.1).

Simply download and save to the micro SD card and use it to flash your Nook.

Voila! Job well done. The XDA page Chahk posted is an excellent resource and reassuring, stating that it

> Keep in mind that the Nook is really hard to brick. By that, I mean almost impossible.

So there you go! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=914690) is a step-by-step guide for restoring your Nook Color to stock firmware.

Comment: I would say that it would be better to put the "steps" here, instead of just linking somewhere else. still link to the source, and give credit, but what if the post is "deleted" or changed. this answer then becomes useless to anyone in the future.